# Dynamically create variable in Thymeleaf

Tags: variables, thymeleaf, string-concatenation

I have an object in ${object} and a string in ${attribute}.
for example, the object may be a "user" and the attribute may be "email"

Now I want to access ${user.email}. However this needs to be dynamic as it should also work for ${article.name} and whatever else.

I tried following concatenations, but none of them worked

```
${__${object.attribute}__}
```

```
${__${object}__.__${attribute}__}
```

```
 ${__${object}__+'.'+__${attribute}__}
```

```
${${object}+'.'+${attribute}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```html
<div th:text="${object.__${attribute}__}"></div>
```

Assuming you have a model containing the following test data:

```java
User user = new User("John", "john.jones@foo.com"); // user has name and email
model.put("object", user);
model.put("attribute", "email");
```

That will generate:

```
<div>john.foo@bar.com</div>
```

---

The only place where you need to use the [preprocessor](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#preprocessing) `__${...)__` is the `attribute` variable.

After preprocessing has been performed, you will be left with the following Thymeleaf expression:

```html
<div th:text="${object.email}"></div>
```

That will then be processed in the usual way to generate the HTML you need.